# open graph tagging on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies, web

By putting open graph tags onto my website, do I learn more about users of my website. eg can I link a cookie or login to the user's Facebook id (or does the FB id stay anonymous)?

Answer (score 1):

> By putting open graph tags onto my website, do I learn more about users of my website.

No, you don’t. Open Graph meta tags work in the other direction: They tell Facebook something about your page.

> eg can I link a cookie or login to the user's Facebook id (or does the FB id stay anonymous)?

The Facebook user visiting your page does stay anonymous, unless you have them connect to your app explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, so what would be a great benefit of FB tagging then?